How to Import Blend file in web development or in website for 3d website creation
i want to export blend file in my device and want to use it in my website

i know blender used for making 3d models

well i want to make 3d website for my portfolio and i see in Three.js used for making 3d site but i want to export my models from blender to mobile so how i can export them also after exporting them how to add 3d model to website.

Maybe look at verge3d https://www.soft8soft.com/verge3d/

It is very unlikely that whatever 3D display system you can use in a webpage will support the Blend format natively, so you will first have to export your model. What format to use depends on what web technology you are using to display your model and what it supports, which is outside the scope of this site. However, I suggest that, if possible, you use a pre-existing service such as Sketchfab. I am fairly certain they have an embedded viewing option for just this scenario.
